# Can 2 singleton classes reference each other?

Tags: php, oop, singleton

Why does this not work? Shouldn't each instance simply reference each other once?

```
class foo {
    private static $instance;
    private function __construct() {
    $test = bar::get_instance();
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new foo();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

class bar {
    private static $instance;
    public function __construct() {
    $test = foo::get_instance();
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new bar();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

$test = foo::get_instance();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have what's known as a [*circular-dependency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). A needs B to complete to construct, and B needs A to complete to construct.  So it goes round and round forever.

Basically, what's happening is that `self::$instance` on each class doesn't get populated until `new class()` finishes.  So in the constructor, you're calling the other `getInstance`.  But every time you hit `get_instance()`, `self::$instance` is still null because the previous `new` never finsihed.  And round and round you go.  It will keep going until the end.

Instead, add it in after construction:

```
class foo {
    private static $instance;
    private function __construct() {
    }
    private function setBar(bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new foo();
            self::$instance->setBar(bar::get_instance());
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

class bar {
    private static $instance;
    public function __construct() {
    }
    private function setFoo(foo $foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
    public static function get_instance() {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new bar();
            self::$instance->setFoo(foo::get_instance());
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

However, I would **really** suggest re-architecting your relationships and classes so that you [Inject the Dependencies](http://www.phparch.com/2010/03/static-methods-vs-singletons-choose-neither/) rather than making self-dependent singletons.

Comment: @pmmmm: if this answer solves your problem, [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) by ticking the check-box outline below the score of this answer.  It helps to show others who may come with the same problem what helped you.

Comment: That is not a race condition.  Read the article you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

You will have an infinite recursion:

foo::get_instance(); -> foo constructor -> bar::get_instance() -> bar constructur -> foo::get_instance(); -> ...

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the constructors for both classes execute only once, since an instance exist get_instance() should not trigger new

Comment: No, you call the constructor which returns an instance to a class. Because the constructors will never return due to the infinite recursion, no assignment to `$instance` will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Because neither constructor ever returns. Neither `foo` or `bar` instance is ever created, because they keep refernecing each other.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a case of recursion. The call stack looks like this:

```
foo::get_instance() 
foo::__construct()
bar::get_instance()
bar::__construct()
foo::get_instance()
foo::__construct()
...
```

The reason this is happening is that when foo::get_Instance is called from the bar constructor, it is still in the context of the initial call to `foo::get_Instance` and has not set the `$instance` value yet.

There are a number of ways you can address this, but I would first ask why you need to have them as members of each other.

If you don't need to, you would simply call `foo::get_instance` and `bar::get_instance` at the points that you need to access them.